# can the $rank$ of this matrix ever be 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I have a system of linear equations:

$x-y+2z-t=1$

$2x-3y-z+t=-1$

$x+ (\alpha - 4)z=\alpha - 3$

I have already found that this system has a solution for any value of $\alpha$. Now I need to find the $\alpha$ for which the matrix of the system has a $rank = 2$. The row echelon form of the matrix looks like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 && -1 && 2 && -1 && 1 \\
0 && -1 && -5 && 3 && -3 \\
0 && 0 && \alpha - 11 && 4 && \alpha - 7
\end{bmatrix}$

I don't think that the $rank$ of this matrix could be 2 for any value of $\alpha$ but the problem specifically asks for me to prove that it can. Maybe I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The rank cannot be two because $(1,0,0), (-1,-1,0), (-1,3,4)$ are already linearly independent.

Comment: okay, so I was right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your transformation to row echolon form is correct.

You are correct, there is no choice for $\alpha$ such that the matrix has rank 2 (both the matrix of the coefficients as well as the augmented including the r.h.s.) since there is no choice for $\alpha$ which will make the last row linear dependent of the first two rows, as can be seen in the echelon form.